# Python sqlite: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'59+11'

Tags: python, sqlite

Getting errors when querying for specific dates:

```
sql_db = sqlite3.connect("histories.db",detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
sql_cursor = sql_db.cursor()

# sql_args printed from terminal prompt
sql_args = ('UO9', datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 18, 13, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 5, 12, 59, 59, 999999, tzinfo=<UTC>))

sql_cursor.execute("""SELECT timestamp as "[timestamp]",value FROM histories WHERE id=? AND timestamp>=? AND timestamp<?""", sql_args)
```

The error output is below:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 70, in convert_timestamp
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, timepart_full[0].split(b":"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'59+11'
```

Not sure what the problem could be here, it doesn't break all the time which is what makes it all the more confusing.

Any ideas for how to get around this?

Comment: It seems like it is choking on timezones (hh:mm:ss+zz). In this case the time zone is +11 (and the seconds 59, resulting in 59+11). Maybe you can have a look at https://bugs.python.org/issue19065 and see if that gets you any further. As I am in time zone +1, I'm heading for bed now. Enjoy the rest of your day!

Comment: This is [a](https://bugs.python.org/issue19065) [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue29099) in the `sqlite` module.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it failed there. Seems to think that the entire of '59+11' is supposed to be the entire integer. Thanks for the reference! I'll look into it!

Comment: @Blender: That sucks a bit. It's been a known bug since the end of December 2016 and no activity since mid January 2017.

Should I worry this won't be fixed? If so, I might just have to format the datetime strings myself

Comment: @candronikos: Django handles it by registering its own converter for the format: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py#L38-L40. You should be able to do something similar by excising the relevant code from Django.

Comment: @candronikos: If you don't care about installing heavy dependencies, just install Django and `import django.db.backends.sqlite3.base`. It should automatically register the converters globally.